# how should i design this predicate in prolog?

Tags: list, prolog

I have to write a predicate called `stepup(L, Z, X)`, where `L` is a list and `Z` and `X` are the integers. It should return `true` if the `Z` can be stepped into `X` using legal steps given by the user in the list.

For example

```
 stepup([7, 12, 19], 6, 32)
```

should return `true` since `6 + 7 + 7 + 12 = 32`
starting number should always be `Z` (here 6) and the rule should only use steps from the list. The rule should work for all sizes, `(Z, X)` are always positive.

I started with this

```
step([V|S],A,D):- 
   sum is A+V,
   (sum=A -> write('true') 
   ; step(S,sum,D).
```

but not sure how to proceed

Comment: Perhaps you could be more specific: what have you done so far, and at which point are you stuck?

Comment: I can't figure out where to start ! Any help?

Comment: Is it the algorithm, or the language: are you stuck at formualting  to yourself the steps need to be done, or are stuck at coding it?

Comment: At coding!! i m new to prolog and don't have that much experience!

Comment: OK, so here's a suggestion how you'll hopefully get people to answer your question. Edit your post above so that you add 1. an explanation what you think are the logical steps that need to be done, and 2. the most specific Prolog thing you can think of that left you stuck.

Comment: If you really don't know where to start, then my suggestion would be to get a good Prolog book and/or Google a Prolog tutorial and start to learn how the language works. One of the first things you'll find is that Prolog doesn't have any *functions*. It has *predicates*.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this helps:

```
stepup(_,I,I).
stepup(Steps,I0,I) :-
   I0 < I,
   member(Step,Steps),
   I1 is I0 + Step,
   stepup(Steps,I1,I).
```

Let's put it to use!

```
?- stepup([7,12,19],6,31).
false.

?- stepup([7,12,19],6,32).
true ;
true ;
true ;
true ;
true ;
false.
```

Note that the redundant answers in the second query are due to the different ways to step up from `6` to `32` using steps `[7,12,19]`.

Comment: A higher-order function would be in order here. What would be a good name? `closure/3` is already taking (for loop detecting closure).